# Alternatives to SQL Server CE?

Tags: database, sql-server-ce

What good alternatives are there to SQL Server CE?

I was also thinking of writing something of my own. But I don't know about performance with 40,000 - 100,000 rows.

All data will be only in string format and it will be only one column. So is it actually worth writing my own data storage?

I will not need to order or sort data in any way, just to add and remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).  I guess it really depends on your feature set.  Are you going to be ordering the data often?  Only selecting a subset?  Or loading the entire thing into memory all at once for some reason?

Comment: I would probably still use SQLite.  It would be easier to add new functionality in the future and its pretty quick to hit the ground running with it => http://system.data.sqlite.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to store a single list of strings, and always load/save them all at once, then a simple text file will be the fastest and easiest.

As soon as you want to do queries etc it this is no longer true.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```

Comment: or a comma separated file (csv) can do the job also na?